# Creating a folder and add Excelsheets in Python

Tags: python, excel

I'm learning Python and I want to create a folder where I can store my Excel sheets.

with create_dir() I'm creating a folder

```
def create_dir(directory):
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
```

with create_file() I'm creating a Excel File

```
def create_file():
    data = xlsxwriter.Workbook('data.xlsx')

    if not os.path.isfile(data):
        worksheet1 = data.add_worksheet("Worksheet")
        data.close()
```

But how can I store this Excel file in my directory and not on the current path?

Right now I can create a folder and Excel Sheet separately. But I want to create the Excel Sheet in my folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically when you create your `Workbook` with your `filename`, your filename could be under some folder.

```
workbook  = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r"folder_name/filename.xlsx")
```